# Getting a list of cities supporting ARGeoTrackingConfiguration

Tags: geolocation, augmented-reality, arkit

At WWDC 2020 Apple announced that ARKit `Geo Tracking` is supported in 5 main cities in USA:

- Chicago
- Los Angeles
- Miami
- New York
- San Francisco

I couldn't find any info about it on developers' resource. So the only way to find out is there a support of this config is to use `.isSupported` property:

```swift
if !ARGeoTrackingConfiguration.isSupported {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let udMessage = "unsupportedDeviceMessage"
    window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(
                                                       withIdentifier: udMessage)
}
```

Is there a replenishment of the list of cities supporting ARGeoTrackingConfig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a list on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/argeotrackingconfiguration.

But this may or may not be updated properly, who knows.